# Override Date Object Error: "this is not a Date object."

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, datepicker

I need a specific date value for my web application. I change the Date prototype. But it is not valid date for Jquery Date.

```
InitDate = Date;
InitDate.prototype = Date.prototype;

Date = function () {
    if (arguments.length == 0) {
            var now = new InitDate();
            var date = new InitDate(2013, 8, 3);
            date.setHours(now.getHours());
            date.setMinutes(now.getMinutes());
            date.setSeconds(now.getSeconds());
            date.setMilliseconds(now.getMilliseconds());
            date.prototype = Date.prototype;
      return date;


    }
    else {
        var date = InitDate.apply(this, arguments);
        return date;
    }
};  

Date.prototype = InitDate.prototype;
```

Error:

"Uncaught TypeError: this is not a Date object. "

How can I change Javascript Date object?

Fiddle Exam : http://jsfiddle.net/fe3W2/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is fixed when I changed  `InitDate.apply(this, arguments);` code block as below :

```
InitDate = Date;

Date = function () {
    if (arguments.length == 0) {
            var now = new InitDate();
            var date = new InitDate(2013, 8, 3);
            date.setHours(now.getHours());
            date.setMinutes(now.getMinutes());
            date.setSeconds(now.getSeconds());
            date.setMilliseconds(now.getMilliseconds()); 
            return date; 
    }
    else {
          var dte = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
            for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length && i < 7; i++) {
                dte[i] = arguments[i];
            }
            var newDate = new InitDate(dte[0], dte[1], dte[2], dte[3], dte[4], dte[5]);
            return newDate;
    }
};
```

Information for apply() method : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/4zc42wh1(v=vs.94).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Though overriding the Date() function works with the above approach, the static methods are lost. So, not able to call Date.now() or Date.parse(...) as these methods are undefined.